# Puppet: How to display calling stack when failing a manifest (or how to get a calling stack at all)?

Tags: puppet

Suppose I have written a `define`, and was able to trap the illegal argument combination. How to `fail` the manifest with a message that comprises at least a resource that included our definition (or even better: a full calling stack)?

Something similar to the `notice{'message': withpath => true }`

Comment: Maybe this question fits better stackoverflow?

Comment: Why a hypothetical question? Please post the Puppet code and the expected outcome.

Comment: @utrecht for debugging purposes. I try to debug a resource (`define`), that gets called from a dozen different places in my manifest. I'd like a simple way to see, which exactly calling path caused a problem.

Comment: @utrecht I know, that I identify resource by its `$name`, but that still leaves me a detective work to find out by what name goes each instance of my define in each place where it is declared.

Comment: The expected outcome is not clear to me. Perhaps you could add some example expected outcomes.

Comment: Please add some code samples

Answer (score 1):

Well you can, as it turns out, but it's not pretty.

```
    fail inline_template("<%=
            def path(scope)
              if scope.parent
                path(scope.parent) + '/' + scope.resource.ref
              else
                ''
              end
            end
            path(scope) %> failed: ACTUAL MESSAGE HERE")
```

It works by using Ruby in an `inline_template` to inspect the scope of the parser. If you are really going to use this, you should implement it in a parser function instead.

Answer (score 0):

1) Run puppet using `-d`:

```
Info: Applying configuration version '1423947413'
Notice: hello file2
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Test::Test_file[file2]/Notify[hello file2]/message: defined 'message' as 'hello file2'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Test::Test_file[file2]/Notify[hello file2]: The container Test::Test_file[file2] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Test::Test_file[file2]: The container Node[default] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Node[default]: The container Class[Main] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Class[Main]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Finishing transaction 69972484788840
Debug: Storing state
Debug: Stored state in 0.04 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.26 seconds
Debug: Using cached connection for https://puppet:8140
Debug: Caching connection for https://puppet:8140
Debug: Closing connection for https://puppet:8140
```

2) Use `fail('CP1')` in the puppet code

```
[vagrant@vm-one puppet]$ sudo puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: CP1 at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:6 on node vm-one.domain
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

3) Use `notify`

```
define test::test_file {
  notify {"hello $name":}
}
```

results in

```
[vagrant@vm-one puppet]$ sudo puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for vm-one.domain
Info: Applying configuration version '1423947413'
Notice: hello file2
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Test::Test_file[file2]/Notify[hello file2]/message: defined 'message' as 'hello file2'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.11 seconds
```

4) In my opinion the most important, TDD puppet using [rspec-puppet](http://rspec-puppet.com/).

Comment: Yes, those are all things that Puppet can do. They hardly relate to the question, however.